# C#..BindingList method

Tags: c#

i had to wait 8 hours to replay to u guys, thats why i edit my post here. here is the whole question; this the first time i works with BindingList and i have no idea about how it works, and i don't find a good explanation..
@Damian
• Add to 'My Classes' to a class XYData which has an automatic property 'data' of type 
BindingList  
• Make a default constructor that initializes the 'data' to an empty list 
•make a method 'setData' that takes two fields of type double and puts 'data' to show consistent with them. If the two fields are different lengths, an exception of type ArgumentException is thrown.

• Make second constructor that takes two fields of type double and calls the 'setData' with 
these 
• Write an instance method Find Peaks that finds maxima in the data and returns an array of type 
double containing the x-coordinates of the peaks. 
• Write an instance method that returns a new instance of XYData containing the square of 
'Data'
i already declared the binding list here is the code:

```
public BindingList <PointD> data {get; set;}

// constructor

public XYData() {
  data = new BindingList <PointD>();
  data.clear();
}

public void setData (double [] flt1, double [] flt2){
  // here i don't know how to continue,, am new to c# :( 

}
```

Comment: What does "puts 'data' to sue consistent with them." mean? What you are trying to achieve is not clear (to me).

Comment: is this some kind of a homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this ?

```
if(flt1.Length != flt2.Length)
     throw new ArgumentException("message");

var resultList =  (from x in flt1
                   from y in flt2
                   select new PointD { X = x, Y = y }).ToList() // set properties
```

Comment: and this code gives a new point with coordinate X and Y and put it in the list ?

Comment: how can i use it with the rest of the question,, and do u have a good link who helps to explain how BindingList works?.. thanks for your help!